# How can Shenron revive people?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Shenron can bestow any wish as long as it does not exceed the power of his creator. Then how can Shenron (Earth) revive people, when Kami couldn't do it himself?

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll find answer from credible sources. Dragon Ball (And especially Dragonball Z) pretty much did whatever they wanted. Even if it meant bending the physics and power rules they've set for themselves.

Comment: Dude, [charge your phone](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/screenshot.png)!

Comment: Do you still remember which chapter and page are the images (in the question and in your answer)?

Comment: @nhahtdh unfortunately not, it's been two years since I read it. Also, reading back on my answer - I believe it's actually incorrect, so it's gone now (but it was after the first image)

Answer (score 11):

Another way of looking at this is that Kami did not understand the full extent of his Dragon Balls' power. You see the Dragon Balls getting stronger after Kami's ones, maybe because they knew how they function properly while Kami was still getting to know his limits. So, maybe Kami could revive people but left it to the Dragon Balls as they were harder to get, and were more of a trial for people; or, Kami just believed, "Shenron can bestow any wish as long as it does not exceed the power of his creator" because he did not know how to make Shenron more powerful. As much as I can remember and can find it was only Kami who said this, so most likely this was only a theory of his.

Comment: The problem with the second reason is that it was Shenron who mentioned the limit, rather than Kami as seen in my image above

Answer (score 7):

It is theorized that Shenron does have the same power as Kami but the difference is that Shenron exclusively grants wishes, so he is much more efficient in that regard when using Kami's power.